# what does Pro→Glu substitution mean?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, immunology

Considering the paper:

[A single amino acid in E-cadherin responsible for
host specificity towards the human pathogen
Listeria monocytogenes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1171471/)

in the abstract portion, what does Pro→Glu mean? Does it mean that, in place of Glu(glucose), pro-16 is placed?

Comment: Proline is replaced by Glutamic acid. Pro16 indicated a position on the protein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at a protein here, which is mutated in the higher host specificity, so glucose is not involved here. What is written here are the amino acids in the [three-letter-code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid#Table_of_standard_amino_acid_abbreviations_and_properties), the notation Pro→Glu means that Proline (Pro) is replaced by Glutamic acid (Glu).

The notation Pro16 means the proline on amino acid position 16 in the protein. You often find this replacements noted as Pro16Glu or P16E (in the 1-letter-code)

Comment: oops.. I shall remove my answer